# No such file or directory - the ffprobe binary could not be found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg, carrierwave, ffprobe

I am using [carrierwave-video](https://github.com/rheaton/carrierwave-video) gem uploading videos through carrierwave and it's not working.

**video_uploader.rb**

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

**video.rb**

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, VideoUploader

  def set_success(format, opts)
    self.success = true
  end
end
```

The error I am getting is:

```
No such file or directory - the ffprobe binary could not be found in /home/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: So did you check all folders noted in the path of the error message, if some folder is missing (where the binary of ffprobe is found) and then (or maybe ask how to) "publish" the changed path ruby searches for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [shell script](https://gist.github.com/xdamman/e4f713c8cd1a389a5917) made my day!

As Bart said:

You need to install ffmpeg. For OS X that would be brew install ffmpeg. See here for details: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: That link is basically an outdated ripoff of [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu/Debian](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). Also, link-only answers are discouraged; please add some context.

Answer (score 13):

You need to install `ffmpeg`. For OS X that would be `brew install ffmpeg`. See here for details: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html